# Formatear con css el contenido de un <object>

Tags: html, css, object

tengo un object que llama a un html sin formato, que no es de mi propiedad. 
Me gustaría saber si existe alguna manera de formatear con css el html de dentro del object. 
Me he planteado hacer una inserción de texto con js (para insertar a pelo una hoja de estilos), pero me penalizaría mucho en las pruebas de accesibilidad.

Alguna idea??

Muchas Gracias¡¡

Comment: ya lo habia visto, pero no es el mismo caso, jeje. Tengo que insertar mucho css.

Comment: Si no es de tu propiedad vas a tener problemas con el CORS, tal cual lo mencionan en la pregunta que te enlacé. La opción más viable que veo ahora mismo sería usar un script para sobrescribir esos estilos.

Comment: es indiferente que use object o embed, verdad??

Comment: En esta caso sí, igual son recursos externos. Échale un vistazo a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776) en el sitio en inglés, tiene varias respuestas que podrías probar.

Comment: Puedes a ese html pasarle dos clases disintas de css con las propiedades que necesites en cada caso y desde el código js quitar una u otra en el momento del evento que necesites realizar.

Comment: @JorgeGuz no lo entiendo. Dentro del object no afectan los estilos que tenga incluidos en la pag principal. Da igual las hojas de estilos que incluyas..